# Creating custom view in SharePoint 2010 with new column and row headings

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a simple list where I am entering a name, a timeframe, and a tag. I'd like to create a custom view of this data where timeframe becomes column heading and tag is the row definition and the name is displayed in grid. What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "simple"?

Comment: by simple i mean just these 3 data elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Content Query Web Part to display the list.

You can add a custom item template to the ITEMSTYLE.XSL file in Style Library/XSL Style Sheets directory. With a simple structure like you are describing you can easily pivot and format the data.

For general syntax and an overview take a look at Heather Solomon's post: http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx

Another good link with relevant info: 
http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-item-styles-and-ddwrt/